# NPM Self-Update only if new version is available from Bash/GitBash

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, git-bash, auto-update

I want to first check if new stable version of NPM itself is available online or not.

If and only if it's available and it's version is greater than what I've currently installed (globally) then I want to run the command to update the package.

I have this command `npm install -g npm@latest` for updating NPM itself but I don't want to put it into CPU memory if somehow I already have the latest version of NPM installed (Windows 10 64Bit OS).

Is there a way for doing this in Bash/GitBash or even Powershell without need to open browser and manually check ? I mean NPM guys must be managing it's self-update package somewhere right ? I haven't found it yet, anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`, you can run `npm outdated -g npm` to check to see if `npm` is out of date.

Be careful with scripting with it based on return code of the command as that has changed twice. Probably the way to go is to check if there is any output, and if so, update.